# Is it possible to install KNative on Google GKE in "Autopilot" mode?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, knative, knative-serving, knative-eventing

Is it possible to install KNative on Google GKE in "Autopilot" mode?
I unfortunately haven't found any tutorial on this and cannot use a managed solution for this project because the cpu and memory ressources of my workload are too high.
(The workload needs 40 CPU cores and 60GB RAM per KNative event which is not supported on google cloud functions, google cloud run or IBM Code Engine).

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If you are open to other platform, aws eks support `c5.12xlarge` which meet your expectation of "...40 CPU cores and 60GB RAM". There are others like `c5a.12xlarge` etc. KNative can certainly runs on EKS, you can even run [lambda compatible function](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/deploying-lambda-compatible-functions-eks-triggermesh-klr/), run [KNative on Fargate](https://github.com/mreferre/knative-on-fargate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use [GKE 1.21 or later, which adds support for mutating admission we hooks](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#webhooks_limitations).

It should work on GKE 1.21 or later, assuming that autopilot clusters support pods with those resource requirements.

[General installation instructions](https://knative.dev/docs/install/serving/install-serving-with-yaml/) should work, assuming you have GKE 1.21 or later.